# How to export data in json/csv without pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using active_admin for one of my projects, and I have some tables with a lot of data (+100,000 records).

Its fine to paginete to browse the data, but when I want to export the data (so I can do custom match in excel), and I try to export in xml, it just export the current records of the page, instead of exporting the total records on the filtering.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module Collection
      module Pagination
        def max_csv_records
          1_000_000
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but that won't work for xml/json, any ideas how to solve that?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing another monkey patch, there may be a better way but this one works

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module Collection
      module Pagination
        def per_page
          return 1_000_000 if %w(text/csv application/xml application/json).include?(request.format)

          return max_per_page if active_admin_config.paginate == false

          @per_page || active_admin_config.per_page
        end
      end
    end
  end
endend
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help for some versions of active admin:

```
module ActiveAdmin::ResourceController::DataAccess
  protected

  def apply_pagination_with_csv(chain)
    return chain if request.format == 'text/csv'
    apply_pagination_without_csv(chain)
  end

  alias_method_chain :apply_pagination, :csv
end
```

To figure out if the patch works you should pick into the installed gem [this file](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/0-6-stable/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb)